# Notation of logarithms

Tags: notation

Here's the problem: Me and my teacher are having a discussion about the notation of a logarithm. My teacher says that the only way of notating a logarithm is like this:

$$^2\log\bigg(\frac 15\bigg)$$

I say that it is also possible to notate a logarithm in this form:

$$\log_2\bigg(\frac 15\bigg)$$

Of course, I'm just a student, so I don't know if I'm right or not. Can someone say if this is correct or not. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Both are correct similar to $9,010$ in europe..is $9.010$ in the uk (or at least for me). I hate non-standard notation.

Comment: You are right and your teacher isn't!

Comment: Where are you from? I haven't seen your teachers notation before?

Comment: I have never seen the notation your teacher claims is the only way, but $\log_b$ is quite widely used.

Comment: Well, I am from The Netherlands

Comment: then how do you write $c\lg_a b$?

Comment: @MaMing $c{\ }^a\lg b$, you need to include spacing in the markup, though ;)

Comment: You can cheat and write $\frac {\ln \frac 15}{\ln 2}$ which is how'd you evaluate it on a calculator anyway.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the notation $^b\log$ is used in [the Netherlands](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logaritme) and in [Indonesia](http://bjn.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logaritma). That it's the *only* notation is very questionable, as the rest of the world doesn't use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notation is a matter of convention. In your case the notation
$$\log_b a$$
is much (much) more common, but
$${}^b \log a$$
is also a notation and you may or may not like and/or use it. If your teacher says that you must use his notation, you better do. Keep in mind that the one you prefer is more common for others, though.

A related example of convention is number formatting: One million and a half in US standard notation is
$$1,\!000,\!000.5$$
and in european notation it is the other way around:
$$1.000.000,\!5$$

Most computer parsing routines expect the US notation wich can lead to annoyances (because my numpad has a $,$ for example so I can't conveniently enter decimals for such applications via the numpad.

Comment: I do use the $^b\log a$ notation, because it's the notation my teacher uses. But on the test, I accidentally used the other notation because I am used to that notation. Not really smart of me